# step plot function in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot step responses in MATLAB and cannot figure it out for anything, I have graphed a Bode plot for 3 different `k` values for the following differential equation in time domain:

```
d^2y(t)/dt + (v/m)dy(t)/dt + (k/m)y(t) = (k/m)x(t)
```

in frequency the equation is:

```
H(jw)=((k/m))/((〖jw)〗^2+(v/m)(jw)+(k/m) )=k/(m(〖jw)〗^2+v(jw)+k)
```

the values of k are 1, 0.09, 4

The equations to solve for v is as follows:

```
v=sqrt(2)*sqrt(k*m) where m=1
```

I now must do the same for step, but am trying to no avail. Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Here is the code for my Bode plot and my attempted but failed step plots:

```
w=logspace(-2,2,100);

%Creating different vectors based upon K value
%then calculating the frequencey response based upon
%these values

b1=[1];
a1=[1 2^(.5) 1];
H1=freqs(b1,a1,w);
b2=[.09];
a2=[1 (2^.5)*(.09^.5) .09];
H2=freqs(b2,a2,w);
b3=[4];  
a3=[1 2*(2^.5) 4];
H3=freqs(b3,a3,w);

%Ploting frequency response on top plot
%with loglog scale

subplot(2,1,1)
loglog(H1,w,'r')
axis([.04 10 .01 10])
hold on
loglog(H2,w,'g')
loglog(H3,w,'c')
xlabel('Omega')
ylabel('Frequency Response')
title('Bode plot with various K values')
legend('H1, K=1','H2, K=.09','H3, K=4')
hold off

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%creating transfer function, how the functions
%respond in time

h1=tf(b1,a1);
h2=tf(b2,a2);
h3=tf(b3,a3);

t=linspace(0,30);
[y1,t1]=step(h1,t);
[y2,t2]=step(h2,t);
[y3,t3]=step(h3,t);

%Ploting step response on bottom plot
%with respect to time

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t1,abs(y1),'r')
hold on
plot(t2,abs(y2),'g')
plot(t3,abs(y3),'c')
legend('h1, K=1','h2, K=.09','h3, K=4')
xlabel('time(s)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
title('Step response with various K values')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the `step` function?  You already have the coefficients defined in your code above for each of the TFs.  `step` takes in a TF object and gives you the step response in the time domain.

First, take those coefficients and create `TF` objects.  After, run a step response.  Using the code you already provided above, do something like this:

```
b=[1];
a=[1 2^(.5) 1];
% I would personally do: a = [1 sqrt(2) 1];
H1=tf(b, a); % Transfer Function #1
b=[.09];
a=[1 (2^.5)*(.09^.5) .09];
% I would personally do a = [1 sqrt(2*0.09) 0.09];
H2=tf(b, a); % Transfer Function #2
b=[4];  
a=[1 2*(2^.5) 4];
% I would personally do a = [1 2*sqrt(2) 4];
H3=tf(b, a); % Transfer Function #3

% Plot the step responses for all three
% Going from 0 to 5 seconds in intervals of 0.01
[y1,t1] = step(H1, 0:0.01:5);
[y2,t2] = step(H2, 0:0.01:5);
[y3,t3] = step(H3, 0:0.01:5);

% Plot the responses
plot(t1, y1, t1, y2, t3, y3)
legend('H1(s)', 'H2(s)', 'H3(s)');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
```

This is the figure I get:

[image: Step Response of SO Question]

FYI, powering anything to the half is the same as `sqrt()`.  You should consider using that instead to make your code less obfuscated.  Judging from your code, it looks like you are trying to modify the frequency of natural oscillations in each second-order underdamped model you are trying to generate while keeping the damping ratio the same.  As you increase `k`, the system should get faster and the steady-state value should also become larger and closer towards 1 - ensuring that you compensate for the DC gain of course.  (I'm a former instructor on automatic control systems).

Comment: Do you require any further help?  If not and this has helped you, please consider accepting my answer.  If not, please write a comment on any further help that you need.

Comment: I guess I do have an additional question, but related to the bode plot. I will update the code in my question, however my friend is attempting to do the same plotting in python and his bode plot just seems to look right, where as mine does not. Again I will add a little more info in the questions body above.

Comment: Is a continuation of my first question

Comment: Never mind I have figured it out, All I needed to do is switch my axes.